# Python Selenium Webdriver ActionChains do not seem to work in any way

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

This is my code. I have tried multiple ways but nothing seems to work. What I want is to navigate back using input from my keyboard. ActionChains is failing to activate the shortcut LEFT_ALT + ARROW_LEFT to go to the previous page.

```
back = ActionChains(dv)
back.key_down(Keys.LEFT_ALT).send_keys(Keys.ARROW_LEFT).key_up(Keys.LEFT_ALT)
back.perform()
```

I also tried using send_keys separately with no success.

```
send_keys(Keys.LEFT_ALT, Keys.ARROW_LEFT)
```

Comment: Focus the title of your question - include `selenium` in it, and explain what ActionChain is failing to do (you did not demonstrate that it **always** fails.

Comment: This sounds like an [X-Y problem](http://xyproblem.info/). Instead of asking for help with your solution to the problem, edit your question and ask about the actual problem. What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When ever you use Action first use move to element and then perform action, a second pause to ensure focus is properly on the element , hope it should work for you.

```
your_element = driver.driver.find_element_by_id('your_element_id')

back = ActionChains(your_element) 
back.move_to_element(your_element).pause(1).key_down(Keys.LEFT_ALT).send_keys(Keys.ARROW_LEFT).key_up(Keys.LEFT_ALT)
back.perform()

# If you use Actionchain for click pass the element , below lines are with a other way.

super_ship = driver.find_element_by_link_text('Super Ship')
ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(super_ship).pause(1).click(super_ship).perform()
```

Comment: `dv` is not defined. Please test your code before posting it.